# Radius of convergence of $\sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty a_nx^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $r$ be the radius of convegence of$\sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty a_nx^n$.
The question what could you say about the radius of convergence of the two series$\sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty a_nx^{2n}$ and $\sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty a_nx^{2n+1}$ my approach was to write $\sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty a_nx^{2n}$ as $\sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty a_n(x^2)^n$ therefore it would be $\sqrt r$. For $\sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty a_nx^{2n+1}$ I would write it down as $\sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty xa_n(x^2)^n$ taking $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{xa_n(x^2)^n}$ which would be $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n(x^2)^n}\cdot\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{x}$ as $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{x}=1$ the series would have the same radius of convergence as $\sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty a_nx^{2n}$. Am I right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your work is a bit sloppy, but the conclusions are correct. You have used the root test.

Comment: For the second series assume $x\neq 0.$ Then the convergence of the second series as equivalent to the convergence of the first one. No test is needed.